# Query entries relatedTo multiple categories in controller

Tags: relations, controller

I have an AJAX `GET` call that should count all the products matching three different taxonomies.

- Product families
- Sectors of application
- Liquids suitable for the product

so in the form the user could select `pumps`, `agriculture`, `diesel` and the controller called should count the products that matches all those criteria.

I get the solution in the templating engine:

```
{% set relationParams = ['and', id1, id2, id3 ] %}
{% set products = craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(relationParams) %}
```

But something is not working as expected in the controller:

```
        $prodCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->section('products');

        $prodCriteria->relatedTo = array(
            'and',
            'targetElement' => $catIds // Where $catIds is an array of ids
        );            
        $products = $prodCriteria->count();

        $this->returnJson( $products );
```

It seems like `relatedTo` behave like an `or` operator. 
Also, is it possible to make the relatedTo behave in a more complex way, like, I want to use `or` for product families and `and` for other taxonomies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of element IDs, *where the first index is `"and"`* – just like in your template (Twig) code – to `targetElement`. Basically, this just means that you need to prepend the string `"and"` to your array of IDs.

Something like this should do it:

```
...

$prodCriteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => array_merge(['and'], $catIds),
);
```

Comment: Once again, beaten by Mats.

Comment: Actually, I think _you_ beat _me_ by about 10 seconds. And I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested, but I believe what you're looking for is:

```
array_unshift($catIds , 'and');

$prodCriteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $catIds // Where $catIds is an array of ids
);
```